How to prevent from_delayed in Dask from creating one partition per input?
My code is meant to match names of two large datasets. The function I use creates a delayed list of matched names.
After applying from_delayed the number of partitions increases and is equal to the amount of my observations. As a consequence the amount of task graphs drastically increases which overloads memory usage. How could I avoid it?
Resulting number of partitions of matched_names_dd dataframe is equal to the number of rows of lazy_results_names delayed list.
@dask.delayed
def match_names_with_country_and_city(name_dealscan, country, city, name_series_orbis):
    best_match = process.extractOne(name_dealscan, name_series_orbis)
    best_match = best_match[0]  # Extracting the best match from the tuple
    return pd.DataFrame({'Matched_Name': [best_match]})  # Return a Pandas DataFrame

lazy_results_names = []
for name_dealscan, country, city in zip(dask_dealscan_names_list, dask_df_dealscan['Country'], dask_df_dealscan['City']):
    # Delay the computation of matching function
    lazy_result_name = match_names_with_country_and_city(name_dealscan, country, city, name_series_orbis)
    lazy_results_names.append(lazy_result_name)

matched_names_dd = dd.from_delayed(lazy_results_names)


What type are you two large dataset? from_delayed with always create one partition per delay result. You either need to batch several function call in each delayed, use bags, or maybe use dask dataframe and do your processing per partition.

they are two dask dataframes:
dask_df_orbis = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
dask_df_dealscan = dd.from_pandas(pandas_df_dealscan, npartitions=2)
I use in the function list and series of these datasets accordingly
name_series_orbis = dask_df_orbis["Name"]
...
dask_dealscan_names_list = series_to_list(name_series_dealscan)
I have tried to divide dataset into chunks before using from_delayed method, but the memory use was still high.
I was just wondering if I could something about computations in the functions itself before applying other techniques.
Thank you for the hint

I think there is something wrong here, you are mixing Dask Dataframe inside Delayed, and looping over Dask Dataframe values from your main Python code, which is not good. How big are this input Dataframes? You might want to stick with Pandas with those.

they are of tremendous size, millions of obseravations, so using Dask is essentiona

There is not enough code here to understand or answer properly, but I would try only to use dd.map_partitions.

The easiest (although not most efficient) solution would be to just call repartition after from_delayed and reduce the partition count as required.
Batching would be more efficient computation-wise, but it might make your pre-processing harder.
